Ubuntu 22.04 VM starts with CLI instead of Desktop (likely after former Update failure)
I'm not Linux savvy so please bare with me -- moreover, I can't copy the console output and have to retype everything, doing my best to avoid typos...
I'm trying to resolve an issue with an Ubuntu 22.04 (Pro) VM guest on a Windows 10 host that is no longer starting with the Desktop interface, but instead stops at the user login prompt in the CLI. The launch by VMware Workstation 17 Player Pro seems to run fine, but the console shows a lot of Ubuntu startup messages before clearing the screen and showing the login invite in tty1.
Once logging in with my usual account, I get the following message in the CLI:
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available: 7: /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdated: not found
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 127

A 'sudo apt update' fails with the two immediate statements:
Failed to start apt-news.service: Unit apt-news.service not found
Failed to start esm-cache.service: Unit esm-cache.service not found

...

followed by a list of ignored urls (mainly the archive.ubuntu.com ones) and closing with a list of:
W: Failed to fetch http //archive/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dist/jammy... Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Issuing a "sudo service --status-all | grep 'apt'" (or grep 'ems') returns no result at all, which looks fishy to me as (if my understanding is correct) 'apt-news' and 'ems' services are both components of the 'ubuntu-advantage-tools' which come with Ubuntu Pro (which I enabled months ago, but it doesn't appear in the 'apt list').
The above 'fetch error' appeared to me as a network connectivity resolution issue, to be solved if I had to reinstall any missing ubuntu package.
I checked for file '/etc/resolv.conf' which appears to link to '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' whose content is (aside of the header comments):
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

Pinging 127.0.0.53 provides response indeed.
But pinging 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 or my own IP (from what is my IP) all return the following error message:
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
 

while these adresses provide a response from the CMD prompt straight in the Win 10 host, but also on a Windows 11 VM guest I also have.
When looking at the VMware network configuration for the two VMs, I can see that the Ubuntu has 'Bridged' networking while Windows 11 has 'NAT' networking.
On some other post trying to solve this 'connect: Network is unreachable' issue, I've seen they're looking at a '/etc/network/interfaces' file which is not to be found in my installation. There is however a '/etc/networks' file (file, not folder + note the plural) whose content is
#symbolic names for networks, see networks(5) for more information
link-local 169.254.0.0

but I don't know how this is relevant.
My assumption is that the root cause of all the issue(s) is linked to a former regular Upgrade that did not end well. To provide more context, for more than one year every 'apt update & upgrade' I ran was terminating with three packages that were kept back, which were including if I remember correctly 'python3-update-manager' and two others. I ended up uninstalling that version of python and suddenly the update & upgrade process could install/update all packages without any kept back anymore! This was a couple of 'updates' ago, not much more.
The sad thing is that due to this limited situation with the console (I can't even scroll beyond the displayed lines) I also can not export files or logs that may help in this resolution process! In any case, thanks for your time and advice in helping me out!

Update 1: I've notied that the last message displayed in the console before I get the login prompt is 'Failed to start lsb : VMware Tools services'. When trying to run a 'lsb_release -a' I get as answer:
-bash: lsb_release: command not found

It looks from the above that the vmware-tools were also affected. After a few attemps to restart the VM to screenshot the error message, it now shows:
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: GNOME Display Manager
[FAILED] Failed to start vmware-tools.service.

followed by other messages all being 'OK'.
Console screenshot showing vmware-tools.service start failure

Update 2: it was Python 3.12.2 that I manually installed last February and manually uninstalled recently which unlocked the other kept back packages that couldn't get upgraded.
When running an 'apt list --installed | grep python' I'm getting this output:
libpython3.10-minimal/jammy-updates
libpython3.10-stdlib/jammy-updates
libpython3.10/jammy-updates
python3-minimal/jammy-updates
python3.10-minimal/jammy-updates

To be honest I can't guarantee that by uninstalling python3.12 (which I did via apt --remove) I didn't screw up things here also... :-/
Incidently, I've just found that there are 'residual' installation records which all are related to python, but unclear to me to which release they belong.
CLI screenshot of 'apt list python* | grep residual'
Do these files ought too be removed with an 'apt purge' or should I not bother ?

Update 3:
Looking at the journal with following command
sudo journalctl -n 5000 | grep vmware

the following output shows several occurences of a 'Failed to execute vmware-tools.service' due to a 'Exec format error'
journalctl log entries for vmware and service status check
How do I resolve this 'Exec format status' issue and how could this have happened ?

Update 4:
A check on the file  /etc/init.d/vmware-tools  show that

it does exist and has -rwxr-xr-x rights like all other scripts in this folder,
has #!/bin/sh on the first line (and three other same occurences further)
searching for 'python' finds no occurence of this keyword in the file

A check on python with 'type python3' points at file /usr/bin/python3 which redirects to python3.10
Running 'py3versions --installed' returns: python3.10
Running 'python3 --version' returns: Python 3.10.12
The above seem to indicate that there is no apparent Python 3.12 reference lingering.

Kept back is not an update failure it is a normal part of the update process.

@DavidDE sure, and I know there were good reasons for these packages being kept back. What I meant is once I unistalled python (3.11 if I remember right), the remaining kept back packages could be upgraded and nothing was kept back anymore. It's only after that (i.e. the last update & upgrade) and VM restart that things went wrong.

Ubuntu 22.04 shipped with Python 3.10

@AlterMind did you previously install Python 3.11 yourself? Or did you actually uninstall Python 3.10, which came with your system (and uninstalling it can break your system)? Did you ever switch system Python versions or otherwise mess with them?

@Esther Erratum: it was Python 3.12.2 (I still have the tgz archive and the installation folder under Home>Downloads) that I manually installed a few months ago, and manually uninstalled, which unlocked the 'kept back' upgrades. I still have a 3.10 version installed (according to apt). I've updated the original question to reflect this.

Initial issue description updated with an issue with vmware-tools.service

@Esther did I answer your question adequately ? Tbh I dont remember the details exactly but I realised there was the 3.10 also only when I decided to uninstall the 3.12 version with apt remove.

The trouble is as I've lost connectivity capability, I'm kind of stuck in a loophole and have no idea how to pull myself out of it. Any suggestion ? I'm thinking of trying to reinstall the VMware tools (from the Downloads folder) but they are from 2023 and I think there were a couple of updates in the meantime.

you can try to figure out why the vmware tools service didn't start by looking at some logs journalctl -x for context around it

@Esther I have found many occurences of the vmware-tools.service failing to to execute, failing at step EXEC of the spawing the service, with 'Exec format error' (exit status 203).  I'm adding two screenshots in 'Update 3' above, which hopefully will tell more ? Thanks a million for your guidance.

looks like exit status 203 that the thing exec was called on is not an executable item, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472950/systemd-status-203-exec-error-when-creating-new-service for details on why that might be the case

you can try looking at the script at /etc/init.d/vmware-tools and be sure that it exists, has a proper shebang, has executable permissions, etc. If it has a shebang that explicitly calls Python 3.12, that could be the issue, and you'll have to see if it works on the system Python, disable it temporarily, or figure out how to install Python 3.12 with no internet connection.

@Esther thank you so much for your continued support!  I've just added a Update 4 section to answer the script and python questions.

I'm trying now to understand how the article you referenced can point at my situation. I tried a reinstall of the vmware-tools but in the end it says the installation failed, without much explanation. I'll see how to bring another vmware-tools installation by means of mounting a cd but again this goes via vmware-tools... hell !
